# How to show a joomla component as a module?

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-component, joomla-module

I'm just trying to find a simple way to show a joomla component as a module, do u guys know how to get this done?

BTW, I am using Joomla 1.5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Joomla API defines Components and Modules as two different things.  You can't plug a component into a place where a module goes.

You can create a module plug-in that displays information from the component.  For example, most calendaring components also ship with a module so you can display a small calender in the side-bar.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of extensions that do this already. Take your pick -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/embed-a-include